# Cómo hacer correctamente el comando git pull cuando tienes cambios locales

Tags: git, github

tengo un repositorio en github, el cual estoy actualizando frecuentemente desde mi pc.

este repositorio lo clone en el un servidor virtual de digitalocean, entonces cuando hago cambios en mi maquina personal luego hago el `git add .` `git commit - m "asdasd"`, `git push origin master`, entonces luego toca hacer `git pull origin master` en el servidor virtual (producto final).

Venia trabajando correctamente con el `git pull..`, y el problema se presento desde que di permisos a una carpeta del proyecto (era necesario no dejaba subir archivos).

```
sudo chown -R www-data: carpeta
sudo chmod -R 755 carpeta
```

Pero luego que realice mas cambios en el proyecto e iba a reflejar los cambios en el servidor, me salio el error

`Desde https://github.com/usuario/poryecto branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD Actualizando 11737225..6422c0ff error: Los cambios locales de los siguientes archivos serán sobrescritos al fusionar: carpeta/archivo.js Por favor, confirma tus cambios o aguárdalos antes de fusionar. Abortando`

Tengo datos ya almacenados en el servidor que son importantes y que no quisiera se eliminen, entiendo que con el comando para dar permiso me hizo lo mismo que pasaría en mi maquina personal de hecho use `git status` y si me reflejan como archivos modificados, pero primera vez que me encuentro con este problema, soy nuevo, con esto de los comandos de `git` solo entiendo los mas basicos.

Answer (score 4):

La respuesata rápida es usando el stash para limpiar tu árbol de trabajo... así que puedes hacer esto:

```
git stash save "ya regreso"
git merge
blah
blah
blah
# cuando ya estas listo para retomar lo que estabas haciendo:
git stash pop
```

Y listo er pollo.

El `git stash save` guarda los cambios que haya en los archivos de tu árbol de trabajo en su estado *actual* en un sitio que se llama *la caleta* (el stash, en inglés)... es como una revisión, pero sin ser una revisión. Entonces git limpia el árbol de trabajo y lo deja como en l revisión sobre la que estás trabajando... como si no hubieras hecho nada. EL `git stash pop` vuelve a poner eso que guardaste en el stash en tu árbol de trabajo. El stash funciona como una pila, así que lo que se va a aplicar con `git stash pop` es lo último que guardaste en el stash con `git stash save`.

El `git stash save`, por cierto, por defecto solo guarda archivos que ya tengan tracking en git... si tambien quieres incluir archivos *nuevos*, lo que yo hago para tener control es agregarlos al index (con `git add`) y luego hago el `git stash save`.

Comment: ya entendí el funcionamiento, me los recibe (aparentemente) pero no me muestra cambios en el sistema, faltaría algún comando adicional?

Comment: es que al hacer el `git stash save` tu arbol de trabajo se va a limpiar. Al hacer `git status` no te debería salir nada.... nada en los archivos sobre los que ya hay tracking, por lo menos.

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro que entienda el problema al 100% pero vamos a intentarlo de todas formas.

Supongamos que tengo esto en mi PC como un repositorio de git.

```
$ tree .
.
├── carpeta
│   └── cosas.txt
└── otraCarpeta
    └── otrascosas.txt
```

Hago `git commit` y `git push`
Y me lo clono en el servidor. Hago unos cuantos cambios

```
$ tree .
.
├── carpeta
│   ├── cosas.txt
│   └── creadoenserver.txt
└── otraCarpeta
    └── otrascosas.txt
```

Aquí no se ve pero he añadido texto en `cosas.txt`
Hago `git commit` de todos mis cambios, **pero no** `git push`

Ahora si volvemos a mi PC y hago también otros cambios

```
$ tree .
.
├── carpeta
│   ├── cosas.txt
│   └── nuevo-fichero.txt
└── otraCarpeta
    └── otrascosas.txt
```

Y ago `commit` y `push`

Si ahora voy al servidor y hago un `git fetch` y `git merge origin/master`

`git pull` es básicamente la combinación de esos dos comandos. El primero se baja los cambios del repo pero no los aplica a tu rama. Y el merge aplica esos cambios. Por lo tanto es importante entender que puedes bajarte los cambios sin aplicarlos a tu directorio de trabajo.

Me va dar este mensaje:

```
Auto-merging carpeta/cosas.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in carpeta/cosas.txt
Recorded preimage for 'carpeta/cosas.txt'
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

El fichero se ve así

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
modificado desde server
||||||| 0a07b41
=======
mas cambios que dan conflicto
>>>>>>> origin/master
```

En este caos solucionamos el conflicto, que dependerá de como queremos que se vea el fichero finalmente, por ejemplo:

```
modificado desde server
mas cambios que dan conflicto
```

Y ya podemos hacer un `commit` y `push`. Ese es el concepto básico para solucionar conflictos.

Que pasa cuando hacemos un `chmod`? el problema es que los permisos son parte del historial

Por lo que si yo hago

```
sudo chmod -R 755 carpeta
```

Vemos que hay un cambio actual pendiente

```
diff --git a/carpeta/cosas.txt b/carpeta/cosas.txt
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Entiendo que en tu caso, sea por el chown, o por modificaciones en el servidor tienes cambios que no se han añadido al repositorio.

Por lo cual tendrás que ir al servidor ver que cambios hay con `git status` y hacer commit + push de ellos. Y luego ir a tu PC y bajarte esos cambios.